# Get result data from procedure call cx_oracle python

Tags: python, oracle, procedure, cx-oracle

I have connected to an oracle database in python and calls a procedure.
The procedure is being called successfully without any errors.
But I'm not able to get the return data from procedure

python code

```
c = conn.cursor()
outVal = c.var(int)
data = c.callproc("TAC_CALC_MAX_EMI",[54,"5.42.247.83",10000,1000,1,1,2,'N',1000,1,1,1,1,1])
result =conn.commit()
print(data)
```

Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEXOL.TAC_CALC_MAX_EMI
(V_PROGRAM_ID IN NUMBER,
V_IP_ADDRESS IN VARCHAR2 ,
V_INCOME_SALARY IN NUMBER,
V_ADD_INCOME IN NUMBER ,
V_NATIONALITY IN NUMBER,
V_MARITAL_ST IN NUMBER,
V_FAMILY_SIZE IN NUMBER,
V_MORTGAGE IN CHAR,
O_MAX_EMI OUT NUMBER,
O_FOOD OUT NUMBER,
O_HEALTH OUT NUMBER,
O_TRANSPORTATION OUT NUMBER,
O_COMMUNICATION OUT NUMBER,
O_EDUCATION OUT NUMBER
)
IS

L_FOOD  NUMBER ;
L_HEALTH  NUMBER ;
L_TRANSPORTATION  NUMBER ;
L_COMMUNICATION  NUMBER ;
L_EDUCATION NUMBER ;
L_INCOME NUMBER;
L_INC_COND NUMBER ; 
L_TCDC_PERCENT NUMBER; 
L_INC_MAX NUMBER;
L_TOTAL_DBR NUMBER:=0;


BEGIN

L_TOTAL_DBR := 0 ;
L_INC_COND := 0;
L_TCDC_PERCENT := 0 ; 

SELECT * INTO L_FOOD ,L_HEALTH ,L_TRANSPORTATION , L_COMMUNICATION , L_EDUCATION FROM 
(SELECT TCP_ID ,TCD_VALUE  FROM TAC_CALC_DBR 
WHERE TCC_ID = V_NATIONALITY
AND TCMS_ID  = V_MARITAL_ST
AND TCFS_ID = V_FAMILY_SIZE)
PIVOT
( 
SUM(TCD_VALUE)
 FOR TCP_ID IN (1, 2, 3,4,5)) ; 

--==========================================================================

L_INCOME := V_INCOME_SALARY + (V_ADD_INCOME / 2)  ;

SELECT DISTINCT TCDC_INCOME INTO L_INC_COND FROM TAC_CALC_DBR_CONDITIONS ;

IF L_INCOME >=  L_INC_COND THEN

    SELECT  TCDC_PERCENT INTO  L_TCDC_PERCENT FROM TAC_CALC_DBR_CONDITIONS WHERE TCDC_COND = '<='  ;

    ELSIF  L_INCOME <  L_INC_COND AND V_MORTGAGE = 'Y'  THEN

        SELECT  TCDC_PERCENT INTO  L_TCDC_PERCENT FROM TAC_CALC_DBR_CONDITIONS WHERE TCDC_COND = '>' AND TCDC_COND2 = 'Y';

        ELSE

       SELECT  TCDC_PERCENT  INTO  L_TCDC_PERCENT FROM TAC_CALC_DBR_CONDITIONS WHERE TCDC_COND = '>' AND TCDC_COND2 = 'N' ;

END IF;

SELECT SUM(TCD_VALUE) INTO L_TOTAL_DBR FROM TAC_CALC_DBR  WHERE TCC_ID=V_NATIONALITY AND TCMS_ID=V_MARITAL_ST AND TCFS_ID = V_FAMILY_SIZE;

L_INC_MAX := ((L_INCOME - L_TOTAL_DBR)* (L_TCDC_PERCENT/100)) ;

O_MAX_EMI :=  L_INC_MAX;
O_FOOD := L_FOOD ;
O_HEALTH := L_HEALTH ;
O_TRANSPORTATION := L_TRANSPORTATION;
O_COMMUNICATION  := L_COMMUNICATION;
O_EDUCATION := L_EDUCATION;


END ;
/
```

I'm not familiar with procedures or SQL in general. 
Please suggest a way to get the return data from the procedure

Comment: you should provide 8 parameters as input not 14, since the last 6 are of type OUT.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan,
okay, thank you. then again, how do I get the return data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the first example in the [cx_Oracle documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html):

```
outVal = cursor.var(int)
cursor.callproc('myproc', [123, outVal])
print(outVal.getvalue())
```